# Java- Need help in formulas

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, jcreator

I've recently posted here, but again I need help (I'm very new) I got the first part (SSS) but its the 2nd part I need help with, I don't understand how to put a² = b² + c² - 2bc cosA in and sin B / b = sin A / a here's my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CosineLaw {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean sss = new Boolean(true);

    System.out.println("Are you working with an SSS?[y/n]");
    char askingSSS =keyboard.next().charAt(0);  
    if(askingSSS == 'y'){
        System.out.println("Please enter an a side value:");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a b side value:"); 
        double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a c side value:");
        double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
            double answerA = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((b*b+c*c-a*a) / (2*b*c)));
            double answerB = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((c*c+a*a-b*b) / (2*c*a)));
            double answerC = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((b*b+a*a-c*c) / (2*b*a)));
                System.out.println("A: " + answerA);
                System.out.println("B: " + answerB);
                System.out.println("C: " + answerC);

    }else if(askingSSS == 'n'){
        System.out.println("Are you working with SAS?[y/n]");
        char askingSAS =keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Please enter the 2 sides and 1 angle:");
        char twoSideOneAngle =keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        if(askingSAS == 'y'){
            System.out.println("Please enter an angle for a:");
            double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter a side value for b:");
            double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter a side value for c:");
            double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
                double answerA = Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(b*b+c*c-2*b*c)*(a));
                double answerB = Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(sin b/b = sin a/a));
                double answerC =  (b*b+a*a-c*c) / (2*b*a);  
                    System.out.println("A: " + answerA);
                    System.out.println("B: " + answerB);
                    System.out.println("C: " + answerC);
            }
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're putting everything inside the cos and the sin. First simplify the equation.

a² = b² + c² - 2bc cosA becomes a = (b² + c² - 2bc cosA)^(1/2). Then you can work from the inside out.

In pseudocode:

```
answer = cos(A)
answer = answer * 2 * b * c
answer += b*b
answer += c*c
answer = sqrt(answer)
```

Similarly, if you are looking for B in sinB/b = sinA/a, this becomes B = arcsin(b*sinA/a):

```
answer = sin(A)
answer = b * answer
answer = answer/a
answer = arcsin(answer)
```

Also you may want to review some of your logic.

```
else if(askingSSS == 'n'){
    System.out.println("Are you working with SAS?[y/n]");
    char askingSAS =keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    if(askingSAS == 'y'){
        // I change code here
        System.out.println("Please enter the 2 sides and 1 angle:");
        char twoSideOneAngle =keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Please enter an angle for a:");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a side value for b:");
        double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a side value for c:");
        double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
            double answerA = Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(b*b+c*c-2*b*c)*(a));
            double answerB = Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(sin b/b = sin a/a));
            double answerC =  (b*b+a*a-c*c) / (2*b*a);  
                System.out.println("A: " + answerA);
                System.out.println("B: " + answerB);
                System.out.println("C: " + answerC);
        }
    }
```

This would make more sense, since the character you are checking against is now the one that answers the relevant question.

Comment: Thanks,but for answerB I'm still getting errors between (sin b/b = sin a/a));

Comment: What you're doing doesn't work in terms of programming languages. = is an assignment operator, C# has no way of "solving" an equation, you need to do the isolation for variable you want yourself, like in the start of my answer. The second part of my answer was only to show you that you should move two lines inside the if statement. I didn't change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
double answerB = Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(sin b/b = sin a/a));
```

The Math.toDegrees should be technically on the outside:

```
double answerB = Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(sin b/b = sin a/a));
```

Also sin b/b  is the same thing as 1... So I think your equation doesn't make sense... Perhaps sin(b)/b....

```
double answerB = a*(Math.sin(b)/Math.sin(a));
```

Try that, see if it works.

Newest EDIT: the code said sin b/b, I misunderstood. The code should be:

```
double answerB = answerA*(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(b))/Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a)));
```

I assume "answerA" is the same as A (the side).

Comment: sinB/b is not the same thing as one. the B refers to an angle, where as b is a side length. Further, even if B and b are the same (i.e. 10) the answer is not 1. (take sin(10)/10 for example).

Comment: It works but its kind of off the SAS I'm using are a= 49 degrees,b=5,c=7. Its giving me 49.26 instead of 45.4. :\

Comment: It gave me 5.327398075846185 this time around

Comment: But Math.sin should expect Math.toRadians.... And not Math.toDegrees(), try the Math.toRadians. Try the new edit?